# How do i remove all characters after a certain point. Using R

Tags: r, string, character

This is a line from some data.

`"SINCLAIR PHARMA (#S) - SINCLAIR PHARMA (#S)"`

I'm trying to get rid of all characters, after the first `(#S)`

all the names in the data are like this eg

FIRM 1 (#S) FIRM 1

FIRM 2 (#S) FIRM 2

FIRM 3 (#S) FIRM 3

and so on and so forth...

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
c1 = "SINCLAIR PHARMA (#S) - SINCLAIR PHARMA (#S)"
strsplit(c1 , '(#S' ,fixed = T )[[1]][[1]]
```

you can modify this a bit as per your requiremment.